# Can bind to multiple collections in Azure Functions Cosmos DB output?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to create a different collection for every event type,
and I don't want to create a new binding as it would not be future proof.

I thought of it like the blob output:

```
{
    "type": "cosmosDB",
    "direction": "out",
    "name": "outputDocument",
    "databaseName": "DB",
    "collectionName": "{collection}",
    "createIfNotExists": "true",
    "connectionStringSetting": "CSTR"
}
```

But that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use multiple output bindings, there is no way to specify in a single JSON

```
{
    "type": "cosmosDB",
    "direction": "out",
    "name": "outputDocument1",
    "databaseName": "DB",
    "collectionName": "collection1",
    "createIfNotExists": "true",
    "connectionStringSetting": "CSTR"
},
{
    "type": "cosmosDB",
    "direction": "out",
    "name": "outputDocument2",
    "databaseName": "DB",
    "collectionName": "collection2",
    "createIfNotExists": "true",
    "connectionStringSetting": "CSTR"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that would create a growing amount of outputs for me.